# Apply smoothing filter on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have following canvas that has many small (15x15) blocks:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is adding a filter to remove the boundaries between boxes and make the picture a bit more consistent so that the rectangles are not too obvious and are smooth. What filter or algorithm can I use to achieve this goal?

*Please note that I cannot change the way that I'm creating the canvas and I have to draw a bunch of rectangles in order to make the final shape. And apologies if the question is not clear enough.*

Comment: Could you share some of the code? Are the lines transparent? Why can't you define the cell size to be larger?

Comment: @K3N these are just a few rectangles that I have created using `ctx.fillRect` function and no I cannot. These are the output of another component and impossible to change.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter + https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#blur()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getImageData` to get the data immidiately around any one pixel and melt them together on a temporary canvas. End by `drawImage` on the primary canvas.

```js
var c = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
var size = c.width = c.height = 50;
var tileSize = 5;
var padding = 0;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.style.width = c.style.height = "400px";
for (var x = 0; x < size; x += tileSize) {
  for (var y = 0; y < size; y += tileSize) {
    ctx.fillStyle = (Math.random() > 0.5 ? "#FF0000" : (Math.random() > 0.5 ? "#00FF00" : '#0000FF'));
    ctx.fillRect(x + padding, y + padding, tileSize - padding, tileSize - padding);
  }
}

function blur(canvas) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var tempCanvas = canvas.cloneNode();
  var tempCTX = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
  var divideBy = 9;
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x += 1) {
    for (var y = 0; y < size; y += 1) {
      var data = ctx.getImageData(x - 1, y - 1, 3, 3).data;
      var arr = [0, 0, 0, 1];
      for (var dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < data.length; dataIndex += 4) {
        arr[0] += (data[dataIndex] === 0 ? 0 : data[dataIndex] / divideBy);
        arr[1] += (data[dataIndex + 1] === 0 ? 0 : data[dataIndex + 1] / divideBy);
        arr[2] += (data[dataIndex + 2] === 0 ? 0 : data[dataIndex + 2] / divideBy);
      }
      arr = arr.map(function(a) {
        return Math.round(a);
      });
      tempCTX.fillStyle = "rgba(" + (arr.join(',')) + ")";
      tempCTX.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    }
  }
  ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);
}
//TEST
var output = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
var step = 0;

function blurStep() {
  blur(c);
  step++;
  output.innerHTML = "Blur step: " + step;
  if (step < 20) {
    setTimeout(blurStep, 1000 / 60);
  }
}
setTimeout(blurStep, 1000);
```

**EDIT 1 - Edge control**

A slight edit that removes the black borders that gets generated when my function goes outside the existing canvas:

```js
var output = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
var c = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
var size = c.width = c.height = 50;
var tileSize = 5;
var padding = 0;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.style.width = c.style.height = "800px";
for (var x = 0; x < size; x += tileSize) {
  for (var y = 0; y < size; y += tileSize) {
    ctx.fillStyle = (Math.random() > 0.5 ? "#FF0000" : (Math.random() > 0.5 ? "#00FF00" : '#0000FF'));
    ctx.fillRect(x + padding, y + padding, tileSize - padding, tileSize - padding);
  }
}

function blur(canvas) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var tempCanvas = canvas.cloneNode();
  var tempCTX = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
  var divideBy = 9;
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x += 1) {
    for (var y = 0; y < size; y += 1) {
      var X = (x >= 1 ? x - 1 : x);
      var Y = (y >= 1 ? y - 1 : y);
      var overflowX = size - X < 3;
      var overflowY = size - Y < 3;
      var data = ctx.getImageData(X, Y, 3, 3).data;
      if (overflowX) {
        var i = 8;
        do {
          data[i] = data[i - 4];
          data[i + 1] = data[i - 4 + 1];
          data[i + 2] = data[i - 4 + 2];
          i += 12;
        } while (i <= 32);
      }
      if (overflowY) {
        var i = 24;
        do {
          data[i] = data[i - 12];
          i++;
        } while (i <= 32);
      }
      var arr = [0, 0, 0, 1];
      for (var dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < data.length; dataIndex += 4) {
        arr[0] += (data[dataIndex] === 0 ? 0 : data[dataIndex] / divideBy);
        arr[1] += (data[dataIndex + 1] === 0 ? 0 : data[dataIndex + 1] / divideBy);
        arr[2] += (data[dataIndex + 2] === 0 ? 0 : data[dataIndex + 2] / divideBy);
      }
      arr = arr.map(function(a) {
        return Math.round(a);
      });
      tempCTX.fillStyle = "rgba(" + (arr.join(',')) + ")";
      tempCTX.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    }
  }
  ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);
}
//TEST
var step = 0;
var steps = 20;

function blurStep() {
  blur(c);
  step++;
  output.innerHTML = "Blur step: " + step + "/" + steps;
  if (step < steps) {
    requestAnimationFrame(blurStep);
  }
}
requestAnimationFrame(blurStep);
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing it rather for fun than real helping. But you can get basic idea, read on :)

Generate bitmap, get pure color array (for example imageData), get width of image and multiply it with 4 ([r, g, b, a] is one pixel) ([some docs about manipulation inside canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas))

If you will - you can modify it by doing some "put data" loops and multipying directions by 15 to get this "blocky" style!

Then - do what you want. I will do for example purpose:

```
const channelResolution = 4; // if you don't have somehow alpha channel - make it 3.
const lineDistance = imageWidth * channelResolution;
const imageData = [ /* your ImageData from canvas */];

const [r, g, b, a] = [0, 1, 2, 3]; // directions inside channels
const [left, right, up, down] = [
    -channelResolution,
    channelResolution,
    -lineDistance,
    lineDistance]; // directions inside pixels

// return array of channel values in given directions
const scan = (data, scanChannel, scanPixel, scanDirections) => {
    const scanResult = [];

    scanResult.push(data[scanPixel + scanChannel]);
    return scanResult.concat(scanDirections.map(direction => {
        return data[scanPixel + scanChannel + direction];
    }));
};

// mixer filter
const mixChannel = (array) => {
    let sum = 0;
    array.map(channel => sum+=channel);
    return sum / (array.length + 1);
};

// blur edge filter/shader
const blurEdges = () => {
  const resultData = clone(imageData); // (you can do json transformation)
  for(let pointer = 0; pointer < imageData * channelResolution - channelResolution; pointer += channelResolution) {
    const [red, green, blue, alpha] = [
        mixChannel(scan(imageData, r, pointer, [up, left, down, right])),
        mixChannel(scan(imageData, g, pointer, [up, left, down, right])),
        mixChannel(scan(imageData, b, pointer, [up, left, down, right])),
        mixChannel(scan(imageData, a, pointer, [up, left, down, right])),
    ];

    resultData[pointer + r] = red;
    resultData[pointer + g] = green;
    resultData[pointer + b] = blue;
    resultData[pointer + a] = alpha;
  }
  return resultData; // or putImageData
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many many ways to blur. Unfortunately most of them are wrong and result in images that are darker then the original. A blur should not lose brightnest

I have taken the code from **Emil S. Jørgensen** and corrected the maths used so that the image brightness is not affected as the image is blurred.

For each channel r,g,b you get the mean of the square of each nearby pixel and use the sqrt of that to set the new blurred pixel

So if you had 3 pixels (looking only at the red channel, r1,r2,r3) each in the range 0-255 to get the mean brightness you have to convert the logarithmic channel value to a linear photon count. Get the mean and convert back. Thus `meanR = Math.sqrt*((r1 * r1 + r2 * r2 + r3 * r3)/3);` same for green and blue. Not alpha.

The code I changed is a bit of a hack i was going to try fit the important part it in a comment but would not fit

It is easy to see the difference so you don't even need a side by side.

```js
var c = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
var size = c.width = c.height = 50;
var tileSize = 5;
var padding = 0;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.style.width = c.style.height = "400px";
for (var x = 0; x < size; x += tileSize) {
  for (var y = 0; y < size; y += tileSize) {
    ctx.fillStyle = (Math.random() > 0.5 ? "#FF0000" : (Math.random() > 0.5 ? "#00FF00" : '#0000FF'));
    ctx.fillRect(x + padding, y + padding, tileSize - padding, tileSize - padding);
  }
}

function blur(canvas) {
   
   var r,g,b,i,c;
  var s = (v)=>Math.sqrt(v);          // sqrt of a value
  var a = () => d[i] * d[i++];        // sqrt pixel channel and step to next
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var tempCanvas = canvas.cloneNode();
  var tempCTX = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
  var divideBy = 9;
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x += 1) {
    for (var y = 0; y < size; y += 1) {

      var d = ctx.getImageData(x - 1, y - 1, 3, 3).data;
      //============================
      // Change start by BM67
      //============================
      c = i = r = g = b = 0;
      while(i < 36){ 
        if(d[i+3] !== 0){ r += a(); g += a(); b += a(); i ++; c++; }
        else { i+= 4 }
      }
      tempCTX.fillStyle = `rgb(${s(r/c)|0},${s(g/c)|0},${s(b/c)|0})`;
      //============================
      // End change by BM67
      //============================
      tempCTX.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    }
  }
  ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);
}
//TEST
var output = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
var step = 0;

function blurStep() {
  blur(c);
  step++;
  output.innerHTML = "Blur step: " + step;
  if (step < 20) {
    setTimeout(blurStep, 1000 / 60);
  }
}
setTimeout(blurStep, 1000);
```